# Calling function from div and link not working

Tags: javascript

I have the code below. It works on a mobile device but for some reason, that baffles me, it won't work in a desktop browser. Any ideas?

```
<div class="top_nav_option_wrapper" 
  onclick="javascript:changePage('{{ shop.url }}{{ link.url }}','fade');">
  <a href="#" 
  onclick="javascript:changePage('{{ shop.url }}{{ link.url }}','fade');" 
  class="top_nav_option">{{ link.title }}</a><br>
</div>
```

Function

```
  // Function used to transition a page out and navigate to a new page
  function changePage(goToUrl, type, id) {
    alert('HEY');
    if (type == 'collection_flicker') {
        prodElements = ['prod1', 'prod2', 'prod3', 'prod4'];
        for (i = 0; i < prodElements.length; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById(prodElements[i]) != null && document.getElementById(prodElements[i]) != document.getElementById(id)) {
                document.getElementById(prodElements[i]).style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById(prodElements[i]).style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        flickerEffect('collection_exit', 15, 50);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = goToUrl
        }, 1000);
    } else if (type == 'fade' && currentTemplate == 'collection') {
        document.getElementById('watermark').style.transition = '1s opacity';
        document.getElementById('watermark').style.opacity = '0';
        document.getElementById('productCollectionList').style.transition = '1s opacity';
        document.getElementById('productCollectionList').style.opacity = '0';
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = goToUrl
        }, 500);
    } else {
        window.location.href = goToUrl;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Check how many parameters you are passing to `changePage()`

Comment: I don't always pass id to the function. Parameters can be optional, can't they?

Comment: @flasshy, what you mean: _won't work_? errors? do nothing?

Comment: @flasshy Then you should handle it in function like, `if id != undefined`

Comment: Why would you nest a link inside a div and have an onclick on both? Remove one and if you keep the A, add a return false. Also no need for the `javascript:` label

Comment: @Abhi in case when `type == 'fade'` _id_ not used

Comment: They can be optional, but in your case you are testing `document.getElementById(id)` it will be `null` because `id` is `undefined`, you should handle this or pass `id`.

Comment: If the type is "collection_flicker" then there will be an id, which is when I use it. I have an onclick on the wrapper DIV because this menu is for mobile so I wanted a wider click/tap area. I've tried removing it and it still doesn't work. I don't see any errors in the console. It seems like the function doesn't get called at all. The weird thing is I use this same code on a link elsewhere in the same way and it works. Baffled.

Comment: What is the sequence of placing javascript and html element?? Put javascript anywhere above this div element

Comment: I f you don't pass the `id` in your call, `document.getElementById(prodElements[i]) != document.getElementById(id)` whould be equivalent to `document.getElementById(prodElements[i]) != null`.

Comment: chsdk...I do pass id in that case. I know you're right, strictly speaking. But it's not what's causing my current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following changes - I am not sure how link.url becomes a type but you will see the idea

HTML:

```
<div class="top_nav_option_wrapper">  
<a href="{{ shop.url }}" 
  onclick="return changePage(this.href,'{{ link.url }}','fade');" 
  class="top_nav_option">{{ link.title }}</a><br>
</div>
```

Script

```
// Function used to transition a page out and navigate to a new page
function changePage(goToUrl, type, id) {

  if (type == 'collection_flicker') {
    prodElements = ['prod1', 'prod2', 'prod3', 'prod4'];
    for (var i = 0; i < prodElements.length; i++) {
      var prodelem = document.getElementById(prodElements[i]);     
      if (prodelem != null && prodelem  != document.getElementById(id)) {
        prodelem.style.opacity = "0";
        prodelem.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    flickerEffect('collection_exit', 15, 50);
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = goToUrl
    }, 1000);
    return false; // cancel link
  } else if (type == 'fade' && currentTemplate == 'collection') {
    document.getElementById('watermark').style.transition = '1s opacity';
    document.getElementById('watermark').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('productCollectionList').style.transition = '1s opacity';
    document.getElementById('productCollectionList').style.opacity = '0';
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = goToUrl
    }, 500);
    return false; // cancel link
  } 
  return true; // allow link
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it doesn't work for me. Maybe there's another conflict somewhere. The oddest part is the menu works on a smartphone but not in the responsive developer tools or if I resize a desktop browser. Stumped.

Comment: Nope. And I put a hook in the changePage function so when it fails, it's not even getting called. It used to work.

Comment: Very strange... Is the element perhaps covered by another div, with your pendant for adding onclick to nested elements, that might be the issue

Comment: Actually, that's what I'm looking into now...maybe that's it.